# Logback/slf4j - Concurrency issues and bleeding

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, concurrency, logback

I want to log calls from a class, but have multiple threads operating using this class. I only want THAT threads calls to be caught by my FileAppenders and used.

At the moment I have "bleeding" where the data is being mixed in the file. How do I lock appenders to specific instances of a class.

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: (1) how about making the class a monitor? (yes it reduces concurrency to 1 thread in it at once). (2) you log to different buffers w a timestamp (so that each thread has its own buffer). Every so often dump the buffers to a file, but make sure to sort the file by timestamp

Comment: Sorry Adrian, I'm not quite sure what you mean? Any more details?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by bleeding (logging mingled with logging of other things?). Which parts don't you understand from my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure packages and specific classes to output to specific appenders. So consider if you really want a specific thread to output or a specific class. Typically, I only need the later.

For example, in log4j it'd be

```
<appender name="someLog" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/logs/foo.log"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %5p %C{1} - %t - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<category name="com.foo.Bar" additivity="false">
    <priority value="warn"/>
    <appender-ref ref="someLog"/>
</category>
```

If not caught anywhere else, the class `com.foo.Bar` will only log to the `foo.log` file.